# A shim to make make Node GRPC bindings more JavaScript-y

Tags: javascript, node.js, meta-programming

This function allows me to write this code

```
const audioOutConfig = new AudioOutConfig();
audioOutConfig.setSampleRateHertz(16000);
audioOutConfig.setEncoding(AudioOutConfig.Encoding.LINEAR16);
audioOutConfig.setVolumePercentage(100);
```

as this code

```
const audioOutConfig = config(new AudioOutConfig(), {
  sampleRateHertz: 16000,
  encoding: AudioOutConfig.Encoding.LINEAR16,
  volumePercentage: 100
});
```

Is this a bad idea, and is the function I wrote to do it acceptable?

```
function config(obj, opts) {
  for (var opt in opts) {
    if (opts.hasOwnProperty(opt)) {
      obj[`set${opt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + opt.slice(1)}`](opts[opt]);
    }
  }
  return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both the idea and implementation look sound to me. As a nitpick, you might consider using a `reduce` on the `opts`, giving you a one liner. Also, I believe the `hasOwnProperty` test is superfluous here

### Untested reduce version

Note that, per Joseph's suggestion, which I agree with, this creates the `AudioOutConfig` object for you, rather than requiring it as a parameter:

```
function config(opts) {
  return Object.keys(opts).reduce((audio, opt) => {
    const methodName = `set${opt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + opt.slice(1)}`
    return audio[methodName] ?  audio[methodName](opts[opt]) : audio
  }, new AudioOutConfig())
}
```

Comment: Since opts is an object, don't have I need to use for..in to iterate?

Comment: you would `reduce` on the keys of opts, which you can get with `Object.keys`

Comment: I understand iterating Object.keys, but don't understand how I would use `reduce`. https://gist.github.com/arilotter/ff5cdb93c992ac50214742e2a764e4a5

Comment: I edited the post to include sample code (untested).

Answer (score 1):

```
const audioOutConfig = new AudioOutConfig();
audioOutConfig.setSampleRateHertz(16000);
audioOutConfig.setEncoding(AudioOutConfig.Encoding.LINEAR16);
audioOutConfig.setVolumePercentage(100);
```

There's nothing wrong with the original implementation. That's just how it's done.

```
function config(obj, opts) {
  for (var opt in opts) {
    if (opts.hasOwnProperty(opt)) {
      obj[`set${opt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + opt.slice(1)}`](opts[opt]);
    }
  }
  return obj;
}

const audioOutConfig = config(new AudioOutConfig(), {
  sampleRateHertz: 16000,
  encoding: AudioOutConfig.Encoding.LINEAR16,
  volumePercentage: 100
});
```

If you really want to configure it like the above, here's a few things about your implementation. First, `config` is actually specific to `AudioOutConfig`. Not everything use `set*`-like methods. With that, passing in a `new AudioOutConfig` becomes redundant.

If `config` can be used on other objects, you risk executing methods that aren't really there. If I put `foo:'bar'` on the config, it will try calling `setFoo('bar')` on your object which will fail. You'll need to guard against that.

If you want to stick to the `for-in` loop, consider inverting the `hasOwnProperty` check and use `continue`. That way, there's one less indent in the code.

In the end:

```
function config(obj, opts) {
  for (var opt in opts) {
    if (!opts.hasOwnProperty(opt)) continue;

    const methodName = `set${opt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + opt.slice(1)}`
    if(!(methodName in obj)) continue;

    obj[methodName](opts[opt]);
  }
  return obj;
}
```